# Remove exit command from bash profile

Tags: unix

How do I remove an exit command in the bash profile after closing and reopening the session once again as it is executing the profile and closing it immediately.

Comment: Bash supports the option `--noprofile`, however is unclear how you're logging in, graphically via SSH etc. If you provide more details we can provide a more complete answer...

Comment: In future, make sure you have at least two terminal windows open, so you can experiment in one and, if necessary, rescue things with the other.  Use `bash -l` to simulate a login without actually doing a login. Also make sure you keep previous versions of key files like profiles under source code control; that makes it easier to get back to where you were.  For the time being, is there another user you can login as?  Is root an option?  If not, you've got problems.  Which variant of Unix are you on?  Are you the system administrator or is there someone else who can help you?

Comment: Do you know any command that is called out of your profile? Perhaps another user can change that command for you.
Or he can do `su sm25`and edit your profile.